# this program is to replace word compiler is raising no error in bluej but is still not executing and no output window is being displayed

Tags: java

```
class replace
{
    public static void main(String sent,String fword,String rword)
    {
        int wlen=fword.length();
        int pos,n;
        n=0;
        String prev,next;
        do
        {
            pos=sent.indexOf(fword);
            if(pos!=-1)
            {
                n=pos+wlen;
                prev=sent.substring(0,pos);
                next=sent.substring(n);
                sent=prev+rword+next;

            }//end of if 
        }while(pos !=1);
        System.out.println("modified sentence:"+ sent);
    }//end of main
}//endof class
```

Comment: Your issue is here: `while(pos !=1)`. Please think about that and you'll understand why.

Comment: Thnkx now its wrking !!!!      It shld be -1

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your main method is not correct it should look like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

If you want to pass multiple parameters then you can create a method which take your parameters and call this method for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method("str1", "str2", "str3");
}

public static void method(String sent, String fword, String rword) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: *"The signature of your main method is not correct"* This is already wrong. OP clearly said that he uses BlueJ and there is no need to define a method like `main(String[])` there. Your advice is correct if OP would need such method, but he doesn't and you fail to fix the real issue in OPs code.

Comment: And before you think about "using" the info from my comment under OPs question: Don't. Vote to close instead.

Comment: haha are you joking with me @Tom did you check when i answer, and when your comment was posted? why should i steal your comment? aahh bravo bravo

Comment: Ok, you still fail to see that your answer is wrong (in the context of this question)? That's bad. So, no, I'm not joking I still hope that you would be able to read and understand OPs question.

Comment: no, i dont fail i know about that and for a reason i dont want to post this part of answer, i want the OP to search for it @Tom and what happen to you, did i do something bad for you, why attack me like this?

Comment: What? You write something as an answer where you know that it isn't an answer? It isn't even helpful. This is not what _"answer"_ is supposed to mean. *"you can post your own answer"* As I said in the second comment: the proper way to deal with typo questions is to close them.